# Applying a list in a dataframe column to another column

Tags: python, dataframe, list-comprehension, apply

I have a data frame with a list of integers in one column and another column with one integer in it. I want to create a new column that contains a list of strings that start with the single integer and have every listed integer combined with it.

Example:

```
data = [[1, [2,3,4], [12,13,14]], [2, [2,3,4], [22,23,24]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']) 
    
   A          B             C
0  1  [2, 3, 4]  [12, 13, 14]
1  2  [2, 3, 4]  [22, 23, 24]
```

Column C is an example of what I want to create using the info in A and B.
Here is a function I created to attempt this:

```
def comb (lst, tid):
    nrng = []
    lsts = [str(s) for s in lst]
    tid = str(tid)
    for itm in lsts:
        lyr = tid + itm
        nrng.append(lyr)
    return nrng
comb(df['B'][0], df['A'][0])
```

that works if I specify the row, but I want to apply it to a dataframe. I've tried a few things with similar results. It iterates over column A when I just want column B.

```
df['D'] = df.apply(comb, tid = df['A'], axis = 0)
df['D'] = comb(df['B'], df['A'])
df['D'] = [comb(s) for s in df['A']]
```

I just want to create a column D that looks like column C by applying a function (or any other more appropriate technique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `apply`

```py
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: [f'{x[0]}{i}' for i in x[1]], axis=1)

print(df['C'])
```

```
0    [12, 13, 14]
1    [22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to concat them without a new function.

```
df['C'] = [[str(a)+str(i) for i in b] for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
```

Update: Be sure to convert to str() first.